# accessing parent span object of an anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a list of tags- and wish to add a remove button- this following code is the js I'm using to create the tags

```
<li>
<span id="tag_'+html.id+'" class="tag">'+formvalue+'
    <span class="remove_tag">
        <a class="remove_tag_link" href="#">x</a>
    </span>
</span>
</li>
```

If I capture the click on the anchor tag how would I remove the start `li` (and everything contained in it) using the id passed in the first  with the id (to identify the tag)?

Comment: are they added dynamically ? ie once the page has been initially loaded ?

Comment: Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/M65rC/) of this.

Comment: I checked this in a page and then pasted to the Fiddle, I have observed the issue in my fiddle, but this works if you use in a page.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('.remove_tag a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('li').remove();
})
```

Comment: This could create unwanted effects, say if it is contained in a li on a higher level. I'd recommend changing it to `$(this).parents('li').first().remove();`

Answer (score 0):

You can more easily bind the click event to the `li` element and remove it using

```
$(this).remove();
```

inside your handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".remove_tag_link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the ID to do what you're asking.  This will remove the li that contains the clicked link...

```
$(function() {
    $(".remove_tag_link").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```